# How do I start with this GPS app?

Tags: java, gps

I need to implement an app that can track a GPS equipped vehicle and display it on a map..
For this I need a real time GPS tracker....I want to save the real time data into a db and from there display it on  a map on user request..  I have it on mind like that but how do I proceed, starting with the hardware which GPS device is most eligible, and how can I interact with the GPS tracker to retrieve its position?

Comment: We need a lot more information than this. You could use anything from a custom gps chip to an android phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard for GPS devices is NMEA 0183. so you are going to either work with that format directly, find a library that works with it directly (probably the most likely option) or find a vendor specific library / API.

NMEA 0183 is getting a bit dated and actually specifies an RS-232 serial connection. Few (if any?) modern GPS devices have such connections, instead they use USB and then the manufacturer supplies a driver which makes it look like an NMEA 0183 device on a COM port.

You don't mention which platform you are using. If you can restrict yourself to Windosw 7, then Windows 7 has a new "Location and Sensors API". I've dabbled with it a little bit, and assuming you can get a practical driver for your GPS driver, this would be an easy option to implement in something like C/C++. I don't have any experience with Java->Windows API functions - so this might a complication too many.